# Trying to make my application compatible with Tablets in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, tablet

I'm trying to make Google play recognize that my application works on tablets. Its giving me these two "optimization" suggestions:

"Take advantage of extra screen area available in tablets"
"Declare hardware feature dependencies properly"

Actually, my application runs on opengl almost all the time, but i have a small code for when it takes a picture.

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="totalcross.android"
  android:versionCode="-1"
  android:versionName="!1.0!"
  android:sharedUserId="totalcross.app.sharedid"
>

<!-- ATTENTION: THIS IS *** NOT *** FOR THE SINGLE APK - THERE'S ANOTHER MANIFEST FILE 
FOR STANDARD SINGLE APK APPLICATIONS AT
P:\gitrepo\TotalCross\TotalCrossVM\builders\android\apps\tcvm\AndroidManifest.xml -->

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="TotalCross Virtual Machine"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity android:name=".Loader" 
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|fontScale|keyboard" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    />
    <activity android:name=".RouteViewer"/>
    <activity android:name=".TouchImageViewer" />
    <activity android:name=".WebViewer" />
    <activity android:name=".CameraViewer" />
    <activity android:name=".MapViewer" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false" />
    <activity android:name=".CaptureActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="landscape"
             android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
             android:stateNotNeeded="true"
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="totalcross.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
</manifest>
```

AS you can se, i specified that all my feature and permissions are NOT required, and also specified all possible screen sizes.

My application runs on tablets since they released the first tablet, but only this week i added it to Google Play.

One other thing that is annoying is that i have to keep generating new versions and upload to production to descover if my tries worked or not. If we could have an application that checks that, it would be MUCH faster.

all the best

guich

Comment: Searching dozens of posts, i added this, without any results:
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="14" /> <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true"/>
`

Comment: Ok, one of the messages went away when i replaced my 10" screen shot by a colored one. Seems that they look the amount of white space on the uploaded screenshots. 
The other problem still remains

Answer (score 2):

"Take advantage of extra screen area available in tablets"

Went away when i replaced my 10" screen shot by a colored one. Seems that they look the amount of white space on the uploaded screenshots. Has nothing to do with the AndroidManifest.xml.

"Declare hardware feature dependencies properly"

Look at this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

In my case, i added these:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false"/>
```